# How do I load multiple images (approximately 100 images) from a folder to asp: image buttons using any loop?

Tags: asp.net

**The code is currently resulting in a null value for the image URL.**

```
string Commented = "~/Files/Temp/";
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(MapPath(Commented));
        FileInfo[] suppportimage = dir.GetFiles();
        ArrayList listItems = new ArrayList();
        int j = 1;
        foreach (FileInfo info in suppportimage)
        {
            listItems.Add(info);
            string strFileExtention = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(info.ToString()).ToUpper();
            if (strFileExtention == ".JPEG || strFileExtention.ToUpper() == ".JPG")
            {
                    ((WebControl)(panelx.FindControl("imgSupport0" + j))).Attributes["ImageUrl"] = Commented + info;
                    j++;

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a repeater, or even better is consider a GridView.

So, say this markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"
    CssClass="table table-hover"
    AutoGenerateColumns="false"
    Width="40%">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date" ItemStyle-Width="180px" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="File Name" HeaderText="File Name" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Download" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="cmdDownLoad"
                    runat="server"
                    Width="128"
                    ImageUrl='<%# Eval("URL") %>'
                    OnClick="cmdDownLoad_Click" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

So, with above, all we do is feed the GridView the list of images from a folder. Say, like this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadData();
    }

    void LoadData()
    {

        DataTable MyTable = new DataTable();
        MyTable.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(string));
        MyTable.Columns.Add("File Name", typeof(string));
        MyTable.Columns.Add("URL", typeof(string));

        var strFolder = Server.MapPath("~/Content/Fighters");
        DirectoryInfo MyDir = new DirectoryInfo(strFolder);
        FileInfo[] MyFiles = MyDir.GetFiles("*.*");

        foreach (FileInfo MyFile in MyFiles)
        {
            DataRow MyNewRow = MyTable.NewRow();
            MyNewRow["Date"] = MyFile.LastAccessTime.ToString();
            MyNewRow["File Name"] = MyFile.Name;
            MyNewRow["URL"] = "~/Content/Fighters/" + MyFile.Name;
            MyTable.Rows.Add(MyNewRow); 
        }

        GridView1.DataSource = MyTable;
        GridView1.DataBind();

    }
```

And the result is this:

[image]

So, the above will result in a new image button for each picture.

The row information such as file name and row index based on a given image button row click can be had with this code:

```
    protected void cmdDownLoad_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        ImageButton btn = (ImageButton)sender;
        GridViewRow gRow = (GridViewRow)btn.NamingContainer;
        Debug.Print($"Row index click = {gRow.RowIndex}");
        Debug.Print($"File name =  {btn.ImageUrl}");

        string sFileFullPath = Server.MapPath(btn.ImageUrl);
        string sFileOnly = Path.GetFileName(sFileFullPath);

        // download file
        string sMineType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(sFileFullPath);
        Response.ContentType = sMineType;
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + sFileOnly);
        Response.TransmitFile(sFileFullPath);

    }
```